# Download mp3 file using amazon link

Tags: c#, html, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am getting a s3 amazon url from third party.
Whenever I try to hit this url and download the file from this link it expire.
I am not getting how to download this file from link.
Here is the link.

https://s3.amazonaws.com/telephony-recorder-prod/fe3b51e5-b8c9-4ff4-b7cd-0f86901fe67b/2023-06-09/bbdede88-06e4-11ee-b0e0-02420a0de768-1686329007.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIASDC5E2MJDPKMH7UW%2F20230609%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=202306012T121832Z&X-Amz-Expires=600&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=1583e6b4ac7d458efa0d7ecf56114542de420dc4b6761d072c5795e0dfceb0ff

I am triyng this way

```
 <a class="a-orange" target="_blank" title="Download mp3" 
       href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/telephony-recorder-prod/fe3b51e5- 
        b8c9-4ff4-b7cd-0f86901fe67b/2023-06-09/bbdede88-06e4-11ee-b0e0- 
      02420a0de768-1686329007.mp3?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC- 
       SHA256&amp;X-Amz-Credential=AKIASDC5E2MJDPKMH7UW%2F20230609%2Fus- 
          east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&amp;X-Amz- 
          Date=20230609T164332Z&amp;X-Amz-Expires=600&amp;X-Amz- 
        SignedHeaders=host&amp;X-Amz- Signature=1583e6b4ac7d458efa0d7ecf56114542de420dc4b6761d072c5795e0dfceb0ff"> 
         <i _ngcontent-svl-c100="" class="fa fa-download mr-2"></i></a>
```

Any kind of help much appriciated.

Comment: That link has "Expires" info in it. Perhaps they want it to expire.

Comment: But the same link is downloading from their portal

Comment: And what about the signature? Does that match?

Comment: As you can see the link is simply not useable yet because of *"Request is not yet valid"*. Not sure what else you need, the link can simply not be used yet and will be usable later today for exactly 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

It is an [Amazon S3 pre-signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which provides time-limited access to private objects in Amazon S3, which has a limited time until it expires.

It works from their website because **they generate a new pre-signed URL** when you access the service. It will expire after 600 seconds of the time that they generate the pre-signed URL.

Therefore, you should go to the 'portal' you mention and download it via a 'fresh' link that they provide.